# How to set Url image as wallpaper in android

Tags: android

I have a android application that display a image from url in `ImageView` with the help of universal image loader in activity. In that activity i want 2 `TextView` first to set that image as a wallpaper of mobile and other `TextView` for download image from url in device. How can it possible?
Here is my MainActitivity class

```
    package com.example.home.mywallpaper;

import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView setAsWallPaper, save, share;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image_view);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fullimageView);
        setAsWallPaper = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.setAsWallpaper);
        save = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.save);
        share = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.share);
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        String url= ">http://www.asihs.org/mistich/images/Strangest-Planess.jpg"
        imageLoader.displayImage(url,imageView);

        setAsWallPaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
```

and here is my Application class

```
    package com.example.home.mywallpaper;

import android.app.Application;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl.WeakMemoryCache;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;

/**
 * Created by home on 12/29/2015.
 */
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                getApplicationContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
        // END - UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    }
}
```

Comment: What effort you did so far? Please show some code?

Comment: Share the code. What have you done so far?

Comment: i have shared my code

Comment: Try this: (>http://www.asihs.org/mistich/images/Strangest-Planess.jpg)
change to  (http://www.asihs.org/mistich/images/Strangest-Planess.jpg)